# Portable software for encoding and burning an AVI to DVD

Tags: dvd, avi, dvd-burning, portable-apps

I'm searching for a portable software that could handle the following

- accept .avi as input file
- encode it to .vob (Is that the right target format? these video_TS and audio_TS folders, you know)
- burn it to DVD

I thought this is a trivial question for google, but it seems not so.

The difficult part is the portable thing.  All solutions are with an installer.

Comment: Which operating system (including version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portableapps.com shows theree DVD burning/authoring utilities in their [Music & Video](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video) section:

- cdrtfe Portable - CD, DVD, VCD burner
- DVDStyler Portable - DVD menu authoring tool
- InfraRecorder Portable - full-featured CD and DVD burner

Perhaps one of those will fit your bill?

Comment: My (late) apologies. [DVDStyler Portable](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=455) is indeed able to re-author and burn .avi or .mp4 as DVD with a video_TS folder.